# std::list reimplementation for practice

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel, collections

I used [cppreference list](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/list) to implement this simplified `std::list`.

The `CXX_STANDARD` is 11.

My questions are the usual:

1. Is the design is ok?
2. Did I miss any bugs?
3. Anything else?

The list implementation in `list.h`

```
//
// Created by shiby on 23-6-26.
//

#ifndef CPPDATASTRUCTURE_LIST_H
#define CPPDATASTRUCTURE_LIST_H


#include <stdexcept>

template<typename T>
class List {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = T &;
    using const_reference = const T &;

    class iterator;

    class const_iterator; /* const_iterator != const iterator */


private:
    struct node_type {
        value_type data;
        node_type *previous;
        node_type *next;

        node_type(const value_type data_,
                  node_type *previous_,
                  node_type *next_ = nullptr) : data(data_),
                                                previous(previous_),
                                                next(next_) {};
    };

    node_type *head = nullptr;
    node_type *rear = nullptr;
    int count = 0;

public:
    List() = default;

    ~List();

    reference front();

    const_reference front() const;

    reference back();

    const_reference back() const;

    bool empty();

    int size();

    void clear();

//    iterator insert(const_iterator &pos, value_type value);

    iterator insert(iterator &pos, value_type value);

    void push_back(const_reference value);

    void pop_back();

    void push_front(const_reference value);

    void pop_front();

    iterator begin();

    const_iterator begin() const;

    const_iterator cbegin() const;

    iterator end();

    const_iterator end() const;

    const_iterator cend() const;


};

template<typename T>
List<T>::~List() {
    clear();
}

template<typename T>
typename List<T>::reference List<T>::front() {
    if (empty()) throw std::runtime_error("Empty List");
    return head->data;
}

template<typename T>
typename List<T>::const_reference List<T>::front() const {
    if (empty()) throw std::runtime_error("Empty List");
    return rear->data;
}

template<typename T>
bool List<T>::empty() {
    return head == nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
int List<T>::size() {
    return count;
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::clear() {
    while (!empty()) {
        node_type *nextNode = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = nextNode;
    }
    count = 0;
};

template<typename T>
void List<T>::push_back(const_reference value) {
    auto current = rear;
    auto newNode = new List<T>::node_type(value, current);
    if (empty()) {
        head = rear = newNode;
    } else {
        current->next = newNode;
        rear = newNode;
    }
    ++count;
};

template<typename T>
void List<T>::pop_back() {
    if (!empty()) {
        if (head == rear) {
            delete head;
            head = rear = nullptr;
        } else {
            auto latest = rear;
            rear = rear->previous;
            delete latest;
            rear->next = nullptr;
        }
    }
    --count;
};

template<typename T>
void List<T>::push_front(const_reference value) {
    auto newNode = new List<T>::node_type(value, nullptr, head);
    if (empty()) {
        head = rear = newNode;
    } else {
        head->previous = newNode;
        head = newNode;
    }
    ++count;
};

template<typename T>
void List<T>::pop_front() {
    if (!empty()) {
        if (head == rear) {
            delete head;
            head = rear = nullptr;
        } else {
            auto first = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete first;
            head->previous = nullptr;
        }
    }
    --count;
}

template<typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::begin() {
    return List::iterator(head);
};

template<typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::end() {
    return List::iterator(nullptr);
};

template<typename T>
typename List<T>::reference List<T>::back() {
    if (empty()) throw std::runtime_error("Empty List");
    return rear->data;
}


template<typename T>
typename List<T>::const_reference List<T>::back() const {
    if (empty()) throw std::runtime_error("Empty List");
    return rear->data;
}


template<typename T>
class List<T>::iterator {
private:
    node_type *ptr;

    explicit iterator(node_type *ptr_) : ptr(ptr_) {};
public:
    iterator &operator++() {
        ptr = ptr->next;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator!=(const iterator &other) {
        return ptr != other.ptr;
    }

    bool operator==(const iterator &other) {
        return ptr == other.ptr;
    }

    reference operator*() const {
        return ptr->data;
    }

    friend List<T>;
};

template<typename T>
class List<T>::const_iterator {
private:
    // const_iterator the const qualified field is ptr.
    node_type const *ptr;

    explicit const_iterator(node_type const *ptr_) : ptr(ptr_) {};
public:

    const_iterator operator++() {
        ptr = ptr->next;
        return *this;
    };

    bool operator!=(const const_iterator &other) {
        return ptr != other.ptr;
    }

    bool operator==(const const_iterator &other) {
        return ptr == other.ptr;
    }

    const_reference operator*() {
        return ptr->data;
    }

    friend List<T>;
};

//template<typename T>
//auto List<T>::insert(List::const_iterator &pos, value_type value) -> iterator {
//    auto currentNode = pos.ptr;
//    if (currentNode == nullptr) {
//        // Iterator(end)
//        push_back(value);
//        return iterator(rear);
//    } else if (pos == cbegin()) {
//        push_front(value);
//        return iterator(head);
//    } else {
//        auto newNode = new node_type(value, currentNode->previous, currentNode);
//        newNode->previous->next = newNode;
//        newNode->next->previous = newNode;
//        ++count;
//        return iterator(newNode);
//    }
//}

template<typename T>
typename List<T>::const_iterator List<T>::begin() const {
    return const_iterator(head);
}

template<typename T>
typename List<T>::const_iterator List<T>::end() const {
    return const_iterator(nullptr);
}

template<typename T>
typename List<T>::const_iterator List<T>::cbegin() const {
    return const_iterator(head);
}

template<typename T>
typename List<T>::const_iterator List<T>::cend() const {
    return const_iterator(nullptr);
}

template<typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(List::iterator &pos, value_type value) {
    auto currentNode = pos.ptr;
    if (currentNode == nullptr) {
        // Iterator(end)
        push_back(value);
        return iterator(head);
    } else if (pos == begin()) {
        push_front(value);
        return iterator(rear);
    } else {
        auto newNode = new node_type(value, currentNode->previous, currentNode);
        newNode->previous->next = newNode;
        newNode->next->previous = newNode;
        ++count;
        return iterator(newNode);
    }
}


#endif //CPPDATASTRUCTURE_LIST_H
```

And my test function in `main.cpp`:

```
//
// Created by shiby on 23-6-27.
//
#include <iostream>
#include "list.h"

int main() {

    List<int> list;
    // 4 2 1 3 5
    list.push_back(1);
    list.push_front(2);
    list.push_back(3);
    list.push_front(4);
    list.push_back(5);


    for (auto l: list) {
        std::cout << l << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "pop front" << std::endl;
    list.pop_front();


    for (auto l: list) {
        std::cout << l << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "pop back" << std::endl;
    list.pop_back();
    for (auto l: list) {
        std::cout << l << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "the first element is " << list.front() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "the last element is " << list.back() << std::endl;


    auto it = list.begin();
    ++it;
    list.insert(it, 100);
    for (auto l: list) {
        std::cout << l << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We only review code that is working as expected, there are other sites that will help you debug your code. Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The code is functional.  It's just that OP is confused about how to implement `std::list<T, A>::insert`, which takes a `const_iterator`, and thus chose to use an `iterator` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Because this is an attempt to rewrite `std::list`, I’m not going to bother doing a design review; the design was done by the standard committee (or, perhaps Stepanov). So I’ll just jump right into the code.

```
    using reference = T &;
    using const_reference = const T &;
```

[You should use C++-style declarator layout](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.html#nl18-use-c-style-declarator-layout), which implies no space between the `T` and any decorator (like `&`. So, `using reference = T&;`. Putting a space between the type and the decorator makes it easier to confuse with bitwise AND.

You are also missing a ton of typedefs, like `size_type` and `reverse_iterator`. If you don’t have those types, it makes your list harder to use as a drop-in replacement for `std::list`.

```
    class const_iterator; /* const_iterator != const iterator */
```

Yes! Good catch! Too many people make the mistake that `const_iterator` is just `const iterator`!

```
    struct node_type {
        value_type data;
        node_type *previous;
        node_type *next;

        node_type(const value_type data_,
                  node_type *previous_,
                  node_type *next_ = nullptr) : data(data_),
                                                previous(previous_),
                                                next(next_) {};
    };
```

The constructor really serves no purpose here. You could just do:

```
struct node_type {
    value_type data;
    node_type* previous;
    node_type* next = nullptr;
};
```

And `new node_type{value, current}` would still work. But you would now be able to use designated initializers, if you like.

Also, again, you should use C++-style declarators, not C-style:

- `node_type *previous;` – this is C style.
- `node_type* previous;` – this is C++ style.

Now, you may get suggestions to use smart pointers here, but I recommend you don’t.

The reason you may be told to use smart pointers is because your class has some bugs, and using a smart pointer will fix most of them. However… it will introduce other, more insidious problems.

I’d split the argument against using smart pointers here into two parts:

- The design argument.
- The practical argument.

The design argument is that using a smart pointer in the `node_type` class would be implying that each node **owns** the following (or previous) node. But… that’s silly. Nodes don’t own other nodes. The *list* owns all the nodes.

The practical argument is complex. Right now, your destructor basically does this:

```
node_type* p_node = head;
while (p_node != nullptr)
{
    auto p_temp = p_node;
    p_node = head->next;
    delete p_temp;
}
```

If your list has a billion elements… no problem. The loop will run a billion times, but, that’s fine.

Now, if you changed `head` and `node_type::next` to be smart pointers, then your destructor would basically be doing this:

```
// implicit delete head
    // implicit delete head->next
        // implicit delete head->next->next
            // implicit delete head->next->next->next
                // implicit delete head->next->next->next->next
                    // ... and so on until next is nullptr
```

That is, each implicit smart pointer destruction has to then implicitly destroy the next one. Each destructor is a function call, calling another destructor, which is another function call. If you have enough elements, you could end up overlowing the function call stack. In other words, stack overflow, which is UB, and might mean a crash.

So I would advise *not* using smart pointers in the `node_type`. (Or for `head`.)

That means your list class is left with bugs, but we’ll get to that shortly.

```
    bool empty();

    int size();

    void clear();
```

These should all be `const`, and they should all be `noexcept`, because there is no possible way for any of them to fail.

According to the standard container interface, `size()` should return an *unsigned* integer. Now, admittedly, this was a mistake. But it’s a mistake we’re stuck with.

In my opinion you are actually correct to use a (signed) `int` for the size. But my opinion doesn’t really count for much. The interface is what it is, and if you don’t abide by it, you could introduce subtle bugs in code that assumes `size()` is unsigned.

So basically, you should probably do something like:

```
    using size_type = std::size_t;

    size_type count = 0;

    auto size() const -> size_type;
```

There are a *bunch* of very useful `std::list` functions you are missing. Some of them are pretty fundamental, too. For example, `erase()` is a *very* fundamental operation on lists; you could basically rewrite `pop_front()`, `pop_back()`, and `clear()` in terms of `erase()` (as `erase(begin())`, `erase(prev(end()))`, and `erase(begin(), end())` (or `while (not empty()) erase(begin())`)).

By the way, `insert()` is another fundamental operation; you could write `push_front()` and `push_back()` (and others) in terms of `insert()`. But we’ll get to that.

But the most important thing your list is missing: copy and move constructors and assignment.

[The rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) basically states that if you have do define *any* of the class special operations… you have to define *all* of them. The special operations are:

- Destruction.
- Copy construction.
- Move construction.
- Copy assignment.
- Move assignment.

You need a destructor. Therefore, you need all five (unless you don’t want to support moving, in which case, you only need three: destructor, and copy construction and assignment).

Because you have not defined the special ops, your list is buggy and dangerous. You don’t notice because in your test code, you only ever create one list; there is no copying or moving or assignment of any kind. But trust me when I say: your class is dangerous. You *need* the special ops.

```
template<typename T>
typename List<T>::reference List<T>::front() {
    if (empty()) throw std::runtime_error("Empty List");
    return head->data;
}

template<typename T>
typename List<T>::const_reference List<T>::front() const {
    if (empty()) throw std::runtime_error("Empty List");
    return rear->data;
}
```

If you’re going to throw an exception for this, `std::runtime_error` is not the right choice. `std::runtime_error` means… there was a problem at runtime. Which means, there was a problem that could not be diagnosed until the program was running. For example, “file not found” is a runtime error, because there is nothing you can do at compile time to make sure the file is going to be there at run time.

In other words, a runtime error is when you have no possible way of knowing whether the function is going to fail or not… until you actually try it. If you are trying to open a file, there is no possible way to know beforehand whether the file exists or not (and no, checking just before doesn’t work, because that would be a TOCTOU race condition).

But in this case, it is trivial to know beforehand whether calling `front()` will succeed or not. Just do this:

```
if (empty())
    // always unsafe to call list.front()
else
    // always safe to call list.front()
```

If it’s an error that can be prevented simply be changing the logic of the calling code, then it is not a `std::runtime_error`, it is a `std::logic_error`.

```
template<typename T>
class List<T>::iterator {
private:
    node_type *ptr;

    explicit iterator(node_type *ptr_) : ptr(ptr_) {};
public:
    iterator &operator++() {
        ptr = ptr->next;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator!=(const iterator &other) {
        return ptr != other.ptr;
    }

    bool operator==(const iterator &other) {
        return ptr == other.ptr;
    }

    reference operator*() const {
        return ptr->data;
    }

    friend List<T>;
};

template<typename T>
class List<T>::const_iterator {
private:
    // const_iterator the const qualified field is ptr.
    node_type const *ptr;

    explicit const_iterator(node_type const *ptr_) : ptr(ptr_) {};
public:

    const_iterator operator++() {
        ptr = ptr->next;
        return *this;
    };

    bool operator!=(const const_iterator &other) {
        return ptr != other.ptr;
    }

    bool operator==(const const_iterator &other) {
        return ptr == other.ptr;
    }

    const_reference operator*() {
        return ptr->data;
    }

    friend List<T>;
};
```

You may have observed that these two classes are essentially identical.

There is a handy trick for writing iterators for containers. The trick is to use a `bool` non-type template parameter, that encodes whether the iterator is for `const` iteration or not. Then there are basically only two differences between `iterator` and `const_iterator`:

1. Some typedefs (for example `value_type` would be `T` for `iterator` and `T const` for `const_iterator`); and
2. `const_iterator` must be implicitly constructible from `iterator`… but *not* the other way around.

The first prerequisite is easy to achieve:

```
template <bool Const>
class iterator_base
{
public:
    using value_type = std::conditional_t<Const, T const, T>;
    using reference  = std::conditional_t<Const, T const&, T&>;
    using pointer    = std::conditional_t<Const, T const*, T*>;

    // ...
};
```

(Or use the typedefs in the list class, like `conditional_t<Const, List<T>::const_reference, List<T>::reference>`.)

The second was hard prior to C++20, but is now trivial:

```
template <bool Const>
class iterator_base
{
public:
    // ...

    iterator_base(iterator_base<false> it) requires Const
        ptr{it.ptr}
    {}

    // ...
};
```

(As an aside, you should really move on from C++11. It was state of the art a generation ago. The language has evolved.)

The rest of the class is pretty simple. Most functions are identical for both `iterator` and `const_iterator`. For example:

```
template <bool Const>
class iterator_base
{
public:
    // ...

    auto operator++() -> iterator_base& {
        ptr = ptr->next;
        return *this;
    }

    auto operator++(int) -> iterator_base {
        auto const temp = *this;
        ++(*this);
        return temp;
    }

    // same for operator--

    auto operator*() const -> reference { return ptr->data; }

    // same for operator->

    // Using iterator_base<true> here means that you can mix and match
    // comparisons between iterators and const_iterators, because iterators
    // will implicitly transform into const_iterators.
    auto operator==(iterator_base<true> const&) -> bool = default;
};
```

After that, all you need is:

```
using iterator       = iterator_base<false>;
using const_iterator = iterator_base<true>;
```

And everything should just work.

There are, of course, a *lot* of things missing from your iterators. You don’t specify the iterator category, for example, which, for a list, should be bidirectional. That also means you need `operator--`.

(Note: as of C++20, you don’t need the typedefs. `std::iterator_traits` is smart enough to figure out `value_type`, and the iterator category, and so on. But, if you’re stuck in C++11, you need to provide absolutely everything.)

```
//template<typename T>
//auto List<T>::insert(List::const_iterator &pos, value_type value) -> iterator {
//    auto currentNode = pos.ptr;
//    if (currentNode == nullptr) {
//        // Iterator(end)
//        push_back(value);
//        return iterator(rear);
//    } else if (pos == cbegin()) {
//        push_front(value);
//        return iterator(head);
//    } else {
//        auto newNode = new node_type(value, currentNode->previous, currentNode);
//        newNode->previous->next = newNode;
//        newNode->next->previous = newNode;
//        ++count;
//        return iterator(newNode);
//    }
//}
```

This bit was commented out, so I suspect you were having trouble with it. I can guess why. When you do `auto currentNode = pos.ptr;`, `currentNode` will be a `const node_type*`. Then when you do `new node_type(value, currentNode->previous, currentNode);` you are trying to assign it to a (non-`const`) `node_type*`… which the compiler will not allow.

The solution is simple:

```
auto currentNode = const_cast<node_type*>(pos.ptr);
```

This will strip away the `const`.

Now, normally, using `const_cast` to strip away `const` is a **terrible** idea, and you should never do it… *but*… you know 100% for sure it is safe here, because:

1. `*this` is not `const`. You know this because you are in a non-`const` member function.
2. Therefore, whatever node `pos` is pointing to, it must be a non-`const` node. Somehow a `const` got added along the way, but ultimately, the node pointed to *must* be non-`const`, because `*this` is not `const`.

So even though you somehow got stuck with a `const_iterator`, you know for certain that the list itself is not `const`. So you *could* force-cast the `const_iterator` to an `iterator` and go from there. Or you could force-cast the `const` pointer to a non-`const` pointer, like I did, which is much easier and more direct.

Let me wrap up by answering the questions:

### Questions

#### Is the design ok?

Sure. I mean, it’s mostly based on `std::list`, which was designed by experts, so it’s hard to go wrong.

#### Did I miss any bugs?

Yes. Because you have not implemented the special ops (violating the rule of 5), you have serious bugs. This class would likely crash the program, if you tried to copy or move it in any way. (You didn’t notice, because your tests did not try any copying or moving.)

#### Anything else?

Yes, you should look carefully at the functions in a list and figure out which ones are *fundamental*. That is, which ones are the basis for all other functions.

For lists, `emplace()` is a fundamental function. With *just*:

```
template <typename... Args>
auto emplace(const_iterator pos, Args&&... args) -> iterator;
```

you could write:

```
// All constructor overloads
list(size_type n);
list(size_type n, T const& value);
list(std::initializer_list<T> il);
template <std::input_iterator It>
list(It first, It last);
template <std::input_range R>
list(std::from_range_t, R&&);

auto insert(const_iterator pos, T const& value) -> iterator;
auto insert(const_iterator pos, T&& value) -> iterator;
auto insert(const_iterator pos, size_type n);
auto insert(const_iterator pos, std::initializer_list<T> il);
template <std::input_iterator It>
insert(const_iterator pos, It first, It last);

auto push_front(T const& value) -> void;
auto push_front(T&& value) -> void;

auto push_back(T const& value) -> void;
auto push_back(T&& value) -> void;

template <typename... Args>
auto emplace_front(Args&&... args) -> reference;

template <typename... Args>
auto emplace_back(Args&&... args) -> reference;

template <std::input_range R>
auto prepend_range(R&&) -> void;

template <std::input_range R>
auto append_range(R&&) -> void;

template <std::input_range R>
auto insert_range(const_iterator pos, R&&) -> iterator;
```

Let me say again: *all* of the functions above could be written with *just* `emplace()` and maybe a loop, and most would be one-liners.

If you also add `erase()`, another fundamental function, you pretty much have the entire interace of `std::list`.

Now, of course, you *can* write all the functions in that list with just `emplace()` and a loop… but for practical purposes, some of them should probably be customized. (For example, emplacing multiple items one at a time is silly; and handling failure in that case is difficult.)

Also, as I mentioned, it is possible to write `iterator` and `const_iterator` as a single class, and use a non-type `bool` template parameter to choose the `const`-ness. Doing that not only eliminates a bunch of code, it also removes the need for a lot of forward-declaring.

Other than all that, looks good!